# SQL query to get max value's data with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following Table:

```
Date         Id    Count
2018-09-01   100   50   
2018-09-01   101   60
2018-09-01   102   55
2018-09-02   103   40
2018-09-02   104   30
2018-09-02   105   20
2018-09-02   106   10
2018-09-03   107   30
2018-09-03   108   70
```

I would like to get rows having max Id for each date and its max Id's count column.

Result table:

```
Date         Id    Count
2018-09-01   102   55   
2018-09-02   106   10
2018-09-03   108   70
```

What should be the sql query to get this result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `row_number()` :

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by date order by cnt desc);
```

Comment: I love the inline of with ties but noticed it performs worse than the window function in a CTE or derived table. Have you see this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want aggregation, you want filtering.

```
select t.*
from t
where t.count = (select max(t2.count) form t t2 where t2.date = t.date);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using self join would be an alternative:

```
select t.*
from table t
inner join (select Date, max(t.ID) as DID from table t group by Date) t2
on t.Date = t2.Date and t.ID = t2.DID
```